# CSS/HTML Overlay Lack of Alignment

Tags: html, css

I made an overlay over an image internally, and the overlay is successful. When I hover over the image, it turns blue, and my desired text appears.

However, the overlay is misaligned with the image and I'm unsure what to do. I don't know if I should be adjusting my overlay code, such as its position, or the image code. It looks like this:

[image: Misaligned Overlay]

This is my code:

```css
    h1   {color: green; letter-spacing:5px; 
     font-family: "Times New Roman"; 
     text-align: center; padding-bottom: 5px;}
     
    .img {width:80%;
    height:80%; margin-bottom:100px;
    display: block; position: relative
      
    }
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    
    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 80%;
      width: 80%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .5s ease;
      background-color: #008CBA;
    }
    
    .container:hover .overlay {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .text {
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
     <h1>
     <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="right" scrollamount="20">
     The Harry Potter Series</marquee></h1>
    
    
    <div class="container">
     <img class="img" src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/kkhp1-lg.jpg?w=399.png" >
     <div class="overlay">
     <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
     <img class="img move" src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/kkhp2.jpg?w=399.png">
     <div class="overlay">
     <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please share the actual code, not just screenshots. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the working code, not just a screenshot. Nobody will retype that out for you.

Comment: also html of it

Comment: will do! sorry about that!

Comment: Also, is this issue limited to a specific browser?

Comment: no, the issue exists with both safari + chrome

Comment: Where is the HTML?

Comment: That works for me, see here: https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/EogVxz?editors=1100

Comment: @dom_ahdigital The overlay doesn't cover the entire img.

Comment: Change `.overlay` height to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `height: 80%` to `height: 100%` on your overlay class. E.g.

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}
```

**[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/EogVxz?editors=1100)**

Comment: I would suggest making your codepen link a snippet in stackoverflow, the reasoning being that if for some reason something happened to that codepen, the example would stay on stackoverflow, it's preferable to keep anything helpful to your answer internally linked to stackoverflow, so that as time goes by your answer's usefulness doesn't deteriorate because of dead links or something

Answer (score 1):

Setting your img to width:80% and height:80% doesn't assure you that it will maintain both the relative coordinates since they aren't absolute. If you keep the width as 100% and then set the overlay width and height to 100%, this will ensure that the overlay covers the entire image.

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background:Red;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img" src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/kkhp1-lg.jpg?w=399.png">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img class="img move" src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/kkhp2.jpg?w=399.png">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

make `.overlay {height:100%;}` it'll work for u

```css
    h1   {color: green; letter-spacing:5px; 
     font-family: "Times New Roman"; 
     text-align: center; padding-bottom: 5px;}
     
    .img {width:80%;
    height:80%; margin-bottom:100px;
    display: block; position: relative
      
    }
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    
    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 80%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .5s ease;
      background-color: #008CBA;
    }
    
    .container:hover .overlay {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .text {
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
     <h1>
     <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="right" scrollamount="20">
     The Harry Potter Series</marquee></h1>
    
    
    <div class="container">
     <img class="img" src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/kkhp1-lg.jpg?w=399.png" >
     <div class="overlay">
     <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
     <img class="img move" src="https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/kkhp2.jpg?w=399.png">
     <div class="overlay">
     <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```